# Returning a String from a public String (...) class

Tags: java

here is the code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

public class createfile
{
    private Formatter x;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);


    String s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6;
    String aa,bb,cc,dd,ee,ff;



    public void openFile()
    {
        try
        {
            x = new Formatter("password.txt");
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("\nError");
        }
    }


    public void add(String s1,String s2,String s3,String s4,String s5,String s6)
    {
            Bugatti v = new Bugatti();
            fw m = new fw();
            fw2 s = new fw2();
            fw3 EB = new fw3();
            fw4 e = new fw4();
            fw5 r = new fw5();

        x.format("%s%s%s%s%s%s",aa,bb,cc,dd,ee,ff);

    }


    public void close()
    {
            x.close();


    }


}
```

Ok so in a another file i have returned aa bb cc dd ee ff and now x.format is not seeing that!!! but i have in fact returned it in the classes defined as Bugatti and fw,2,3,4,5. now how is't the x.format looking at the return. i know i am doing something wrong as i am a noob at this so please teach me how i can fix this!! thanks

Comment: what is `x`?? where its declared ?

Comment: can you be a bit clear about the problem? and post code where the actual problem is.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear as it stands.  Could you post the code from your other classes?  Also, you *really* should consider giving your classes and variables more meaningful names.

Comment: Do you get any compile errors?

Comment: It's really hard to understand what you're saying here. But I'd say for starters that you're using aa, bb, cc, etc. as if they are functions in `Bugatti` and `fw`. You haven't declared them as variables anywhere in the code you posted, so you can't use them in your format statement as if they were variables.

Comment: One advice to save your health, by not getting hit by heavy objects many-many times by fellow colleagues in the future: <ahem> USE MEANINGFUL VARIABLE AND FUNCTION NAMES (excuse me for shouting, this is an extreme case triggering extreme reaction).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what evver you try to do ... if aa in this case is aa you should use

```
x.format("%s%s%s%s%s%s", v.aa(s1),m.bb(s2),s.cc(s3),EB.dd(s4),e.ee(s5),r.ff(s6);
```

(don't know if v.aa(s1) something returns...)
instead of

```
x.format("%s%s%s%s%s%s",aa,bb,cc,dd,ee,ff);
```

anyway, why you use such names ? :O creepy...

Comment: dude thanks so much you saved my grade i only used that because i ran out of letters that i could use for declarations. but thanks anyway!!

Comment: since you edit your code in the Question, i am a bit confused of my answer. Well, if it works for you, there is nothing to ask right now. !! BUT PLEASE !! use MEANINGFUL names for your variables. The 'aa' for example is a string and a function that returns a string and also expect a string. Nobody will ever understand, what you are doing right now. Using numbers for classes like 'fw1' 'fw2" (s.o.) is also a bad idea. it seems like they are the same, so why not use one 'fw' class several times and store them in an array or something else. Well good luck, on what your are doing.

Comment: sorry i posted it after i used your advice.